# Why Live Server doesn't preview my CSS from Visual Studio?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

When I "Go Live" with **Live Server** (extension in Visual Studio), it provides a preview of only my plain HTML file. On the other hand, if I open my HTML file by searching it in the folder where both HTML and CSS are, then the page loads normally with the CSS instructions.

**Does Live Server only work for HTML or am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: That is totally true ! Thanks ! it was driving me crazy..

Comment: how do i inform the forum that your answer's solved my problem?

Comment: There must be an answer for it to be solved, I’ll post my comment as an answer so that you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is because you’re using absolute path for linking your css, for example: `C:\Desktop\website\styles.css`

If so, you should use relative path instead: `.\styles.css`

As Live Server cannot see any path on your computer other than the folder it is hosting.